# Selenium Convert getText to integer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following method to parse some text on the page

```
getNumberText().getText()
```

and want to do a assert/comparison using greaterThanOrEqualTo

So How do I convert the getText() result to integer value for comparison?

Comment: Well this largely depends on the language being used? Which is what? Java? .NET? Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, from this:

```
getNumberText().getText()
```

... create as one of answers was another method, which will return desired object in Your case int:

```
public int getNumber(){
    return Integer.parseInt(getNumberText().getText());
}
```

so usage would be:

```
Assert.assertTrue(getNumber(), intNumber);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

You need to Integer class to do this. Integer.parseInt(yourStringNumber). If the value is double then Double.parseInt(yourStringDouble).

Answer (score 0):

`int number = Integer.parseInt(getNumberText().getText());`

In case that String is not parseable (thus not integer), [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getNumberText(elem)
{
    return int.Parse(elem.Text());
}

element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("something"));

actual_result = getNumberText(element)

if (actual_result == expected_result)
{
   // do something
}
```